# How to clean the "Lorem Ipsum" of my keywords for my site?

Tags: seo, keywords

I have been working on a project to build up a website and since the delay for the initial launch of the website were short, I wanted to have some minimal content on the website ASAP  so that the website could have a good ranking in Google when it will launch. The bad part in the story is that I had some page with a lot of Lorem Ipsum online. When I realized that it was a pretty bad idea to have pages with a lot of Lorem Ispum, it was too late. The top keyword that Google had found for my website where nearly all Lorem Ipsum. Now, it's a bit less dramatic since the real keyword I am working toward have gone up, but nonetheless I still have a good percentage of keyword that are Lorem Ipsum.

Should I be worried about the situation and what can I do to make those Lorem Ipsum keyword disappear or be less significant ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Google Webmaster tools](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2007/04/requesting-removal-of-content-from-our.html) to remove content from cache for example.

Comment: Thanks for the information. The link to request data doesn't seems to be available from the main page of the Google Webmaster Tool, but it seems available from the direct link http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/removals

Comment: First verify your site with Webmaster Tools on the [homepage](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home) after you have logged in. After successful verification you can manipulate some aspects of how the google sees your site.

Comment: I know how to login, it's just that the link isn't available in the menu. It is hidden somewhere, that's why I added the link.

Answer (score 2):

Once you put your real content on your pages Google will recognize that the content has changed and re-rank your pages accordingly. It may not be immediate for some pages due to their low PR but it will eventually happen. If it doesn't make sure those pages really don't have lorem ipsum still present on them and that other pages linking to them don't as well.

FYI, in the future do not make your website visible to Google until it is ready to launch. There are no benefits to prematurely exposing the site and, as you can see, there are plenty of pitfalls for doing so.

Answer (score 2):

Patients my friend :)

Google isn't stupid they will re-index your site and remove the old keywords.